# how to set value in list object from json

Tags: android, json, parsing, arraylist, android-volley

I want to set array value in list ,  i am using volley library for it.Can you please help me how to set value in  **List dataset = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(name));** like  **List dataset = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("name1","name2"));**.

```
          try {
                        // Parsing json array response
                        // loop through each json object
                        jsonResponse = "";
                        List<String> dataset=new LinkedList<>();
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject person = (JSONObject) response
                                    .get(i);

                            String name = person.getString("Name");
                            dataset = (Arrays.asList(name));


                        }
                        btnService.attachDataSource(dataset);

                    }
```

above code only set last value in dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add(name);
and solved my self